# Live Streaming is not work when enable YuvData in mobile sdk

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to use *Yuv* data to send this data by using webrtc protocol and also wanted to send stream with RTMP at sametime.

So while doing this, I have to enable Yuv data by function "*enabledYuvData*" in DJICodecManager after this I am getting state -3 when going live with RTMP.

I wanted to use both together "*enabledYuvData*". and "*Live Stream with RTMP*".

I able to use either "*enabledYuvData*" or "*Live Stream with RTMP*" at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Current version is not supported,MSDK 5.0+ will fix this.